# Comparing an associative array

Tags: bash

I have an associative array that holds filenames. I'd like to use cmp on them to see if they differ from each other.

```
declare -A configfiles
configfiles["file1"]="file2"

for k in "${!configfiles[@]}"
    do
        if cmp $k $configfiles[$k]; then
            echo Do something
        fi
    done
```

Bash returns:
    cmp: [file1]: No such file or directory

How can I get bash to omit the brackets while calling cmp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct syntax for accessing array elements:

```
if cmp "$k" "${configfiles[$k]}"; then
```